# How to insert information into a SQL Server Database with C#?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-insert

I'm creating a form program that allows me to insert information about
mail(physical), that is received in a Department. I'm a beginner and
I'm having problems with the code.

**I use this code:**

```
conn = new SqlConnection(conexionString);
conn.Open();
comando = new SqlCommand(insertarBD, conn);
comando.CommandText = (@"INSERT INTO correspondencia_FFAA (no_reg, fecha_cre, hora_crea, corres_tipo, \n" +
                     "num_corres, dfecha, origen, enviar_a, estado_corres, asunto_corres, mens_corres, usuario, recibido) " +
                     "values(\n" +
                     "  @registro,\n" +
                     "  @fecha_creacion,\n" +
                     "  @hora_creacion,\n" +
                     "  @tipo_corres,\n" +
                     "  @numero,\n" +
                     "  @dfecha,\n" +
                     "  @origen,\n" +
                     "  @enviar_a, \n" +
                     "  @estado, \n" +
                     "  @asunto, \n" +
                     "  @mensaje, \n" +
                     "  @usuario, \n" +
                     "  @recibo)");

comando.Parameters.Add("@registro",SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = txtNoReg.Text;
comando.Parameters.Add("@fecha_creacion", SqlDbType.Date).Value = txtFechCrea.Text;
comando.Parameters.Add("@hora_creacion", SqlDbType.Time).Value = txtHorCrea.Text;
comando.Parameters.Add("@tipo_corres", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = cbbTipo.Text;
comando.Parameters.Add("@numero", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = txtNo.Text;
comando.Parameters.Add("@dfecha", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = txtDF.Text;
comando.Parameters.Add("@origen", SqlDbType.VarChar, 35).Value = txtOrigen.Text;
comando.Parameters.Add("@enviar_a", SqlDbType.VarChar, 35).Value = txtDestino.Text;
comando.Parameters.Add("@estado", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = cbbEstado.Text;
comando.Parameters.Add("@asunto", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = txtAsunto.Text;
comando.Parameters.Add("@mensaje", SqlDbType.VarChar, 500).Value = rtxtMensaje.Text;
comando.Parameters.Add("@usuario", SqlDbType.VarChar, 40).Value = txtUsuario.Text;
comando.Parameters.Add("@recibo", SqlDbType.VarChar, 40).Value = txtRecibido.Text;
```

But when I try to run the `ExecuteNonQuery` command it shows the next error:

> System.FormatException: The Input string is not the correct format.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1) Are you tied to, or constrained by, a certain technology? | 2) Please put the full error code and stack trace if you can, it may provide more information.

Comment: Are you doing anything to check to make sure your DateTime values (coming from textboxes) are valid dates/times and your BitInts (from textboxes) are integers?

Comment: add a breakpoint and get the contents of your command - then see if you can run this in sql server management studio ...

Comment: You're specifying you insert as a verbatim string literal (`@"..."`). The only valid escape sequence in such literals is, I believe, `""` to insert a single `"` character. So `\n` goes through as `\n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

> You can't convert a null value to a meaningful value through Convert. 
>   Your best option is to check for null first and then assign a value of
>   0 (or whatever) to the result (whereever Convert was sending its
>   results too).

```
int result=0;
DateTime val;
TimeSpan Timeval;

String str ="INSERT INTO correspondencia_FFAA (no_reg, fecha_cre, hora_crea, corres_tipo,num_corres, dfecha, origen, enviar_a, estado_corres, asunto_corres, mens_corres, usuario,recibido)values(@registro,@fecha_creacion,@hora_creacion,@tipo_corres,@numero,@dfecha, @origen,@enviar_a,@estado,@asunto,@mensaje,@usuario,@recibo)";

comando.CommandText= str;
if(int.TryParse(txtNoReg.Text,out result))
{
    comando.Parameters.Add("@registro",SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = txtNoReg.Text;
}
if(DateTime.TryParse(txtFechCrea.Text,out val))
{
    comando.Parameters.Add("@fecha_creacion", SqlDbType.Date).Value = txtFechCrea.Text;
}
if(TimeSpan.TryParse(txtHorCrea.Text,out TimeVal))
{
    comando.Parameters.Add("@hora_creacion", SqlDbType.Time).Value = txtHorCrea.Text;
}
if(int.TryParse(cbbTipo.Text,out result))
{
    comando.Parameters.Add("@tipo_corres", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = cbbTipo.Text;
}
if(int.TryParse(txtNo.Text,out result))
{
    comando.Parameters.Add("@numero", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = txtNo.Text;
}
if(DateTime.TryParse(txtDF.Text,out val))
{
    comando.Parameters.Add("@dfecha", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = txtDF.Text;
}
comando.Parameters.Add("@origen", SqlDbType.VarChar, 35).Value = txtOrigen.Text;
comando.Parameters.Add("@enviar_a", SqlDbType.VarChar, 35).Value = txtDestino.Text;
comando.Parameters.Add("@estado", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = cbbEstado.Text;
comando.Parameters.Add("@asunto", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = txtAsunto.Text;
comando.Parameters.Add("@mensaje", SqlDbType.VarChar, 500).Value = rtxtMensaje.Text;
comando.Parameters.Add("@usuario", SqlDbType.VarChar, 40).Value = txtUsuario.Text;
comando.Parameters.Add("@recibo", SqlDbType.VarChar, 40).Value = txtRecibido.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is that, you have to convert integer to `int` in `txtNoReg.Text` and so on.

Please try `Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate.text)` and `Convert.ToInt32(txtNo.Text)`